# optimizing large SQL entity permission query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, optimization, permissions

I happened to run into a bit of a performance struggle with the following scenario. The example I provide is greatly simplified, but provides enough insight required to understand the problem and maybe help me solve it.

Say that I have a large MSSQL db which among other contains the following tables:

- **Department**
- **Team**
- **Project**
- **Company**
- **User**

Then I have 5 tables called **{Entity}Permission**, which link these tables with a **Document** table *(n:m)*, together with an integer permission bit flag:

1 = read 2 = write 4 = create 8 = delete 16 = modify permission

*Example: *

```
DepartmentPermission:
DocumentID | DepartmentID | PermissionFlagAllow | PermissionFlagDeny
    15     |       1      |        1|2|4|8      |       NULL

CompanyPermission:
DocumentID |   CompanyID  | PermissionFlagAllow | PermissionFlagDeny
    15     |       8      |          1|2        |       NULL

UserPermission:
DocumentID |    UserID    | PermissionFlagAllow | PermissionFlagDeny
    15     |       48     |          1|2        |        4|8
```

...etc.

Now, users need to display all **Documents** that either they have specific right to or the documents fall within their **Company**, **Department**, **Team** or **Project**. How do I approach this without destroying the server with a giant query full of left outer joins and ORs? Is it worth creating another table that stores some precomputed data?

Edit: There's also some inheritance involved Company > Department > Team > Project. The PermissionFlagDeny flags allow for fine tweaking, say "The entire IT Company has access to these IT documents, EXCEPT for the cleaning lady and the cafeteria staff."

Comment: How many records do you have per table? IMO, I would store precomputed values per user (including permissions derived from Org chain) but this becomes a problem for large org chains.

Comment: @Alex 3000 + Companies, ~10 Departments each.. then for the Teams and Projects its 2 avg for each company, some clients don't go that deep and only use Departments. The documents table is, however, giant, currently at 200+k entries. Old join query approach worked until recently, the system slows down exponentialy now as the documents table continues to grow.

Comment: You should try posting this on https://dba.stackexchange.com. To avoid issues with double posting make sure you include a link to your original SO question.

Comment: Do you have the join query that you could post for review?